# Perl Substitution regexp with non capturing group

Tags: regex, perl, substitution

I have the following stored inside `$text`:

```
<h1>Bonjour tout le monde (diverses langues) !</h1>

<h2>Anglais</h2>

Hello World!
<quote>Every first computer program starts out "Hello World!".</quote>

<h2>Espagnol</h2>

¡Hola mundo!

<image=http://example.com/IMG/jpg/person.jpg>
```

And I want to insert some

```
<p>...</p>
```

tags around the paragraphs that are not already in a tag.

I tried this

```
$text =~ s/(?:<.*>)*(.*)/<p>$1<\/p>/g;
```

But the substitution does not keep my non-capturing groups. It produces this instead:

```
<p>

</p><p>

Hello World!
</p><p>

</p><p>

¡Hola mundo!

</p><p>
</p><p></p>
```

Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Comment: [Here is what you are looking for](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/801553)

Comment: Is that your real data? It is neither XML nor HTML.

Comment: You also have an angle bracket in `[ESADSE->www.esadse.fr/]` which is supposed to be plain text. If this is anything like XML then that either needs to be replaced with an entity as `[ESADSE-&gt;www.esadse.fr/]` or the section needs to be marked as CDATA

Comment: no it's not xml. It is not a common data format. And I don't want to parse HTML with regexp, I want to parse my specific format to HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps try using a pattern which only looks for lines that don't start or end with `< >`. Including `\n` would also be recommended as you wouldn't want every line only containing a line feed to get `<p></p>` tags:

```
$text =~ s/(^[^<\n]+.+|.+[^\/\n>]+$)/<p>$1<\/p>/gm;
```

Example:

http://ideone.com/p55Ino

Comment: Works according to my tests. Good job!

Comment: I updated the pattern slightly, which should match text that might have `< >` within it... (eg. `Hello > World`). If you want something more general then you could use `^([^\n<>]+)$/<p>$1<\/p>/gm;`

Comment: @Nooxx: Keep in mind that this solution is very limited. All elements must be contained within a single line. If that works for you, then great. Otherwise, you may not want to be using regex for it, especially if elements may be nested.

Comment: Yes, I'll agree. In light of that, I've further updated the pattern to handle some limited nested occurrences containing `< >` (eg. `<¡Hola mundo!>Nested Text<--`)

Answer (score 1):

s/// replaces what it matched.

You can use

```
$text =~ s/((?:<.*>)*)(.*)/$1<p>$2<\/p>/g;
```

Text matched by a look-ahead or a look-behind is not considered part of the match. Neither is the text matched before a `\K` is encountered.

```
$text =~ s/(?:<.*>)*\K(.*)/<p>$1<\/p>/g;
```

The second solution requires Perl 5.10+.

Comment: Very impressive, the `\K` solution.

Comment: @Marcus, I love `\K`. "Insert after match" is such a common operation, and `\K` makes it simple.